# Returning http status codes with a rest api

Tags: php, api, rest, http-headers, http-response-codes

I am building my own rest api in php for practice.  I can evaluate the http code sent to my api (post,put,delete,get).  But when I send out my response I really am just printing out a json.  For example, I build a response in my api like this

```
    public function actionTest()
    {
        $rtn=array("id":"3","name":"John");
        print json_encode($rtn);
    }
```

I am not manipulating the headers in anyway.  From reading stackoverflow, I understand that I should be returning http response codes to match my api results.  How can I build on my api and return the response codes.  I just don't understand how I can do it because right now I am just printing out a json.

I am not asking which codes to return.  I just want to know how to return codes in general.

Comment: Would this be the way to go `http_response_code();`  Also, is printing the json the accepted way to send the response?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could re-think your code this way

```
public function actionTest()
{
    try {
        // Here: everything went ok. So before returning JSON, you can setup HTTP status code too
        $rtn = array("id", "3", "name", "John");
        http_response_code(200);
        print json_encode($rtn);
    }
    catch (SomeException $ex) {
        $rtn = array("id", "3", "error", "something wrong happened");
        http_response_code(500);
        print json_encode($rtn);
    }
}
```

Basically, before stream the output (the JSON data), you can set the HTTP status code by `http_response_code($code)` function.

And about your additional question in comment, yes, printing the JSON data is the correct way.

Comment: I used as you mention "http_response_code(500);" but still am not able to show status in header I user postman desktop application to call rest api

Comment: Hi @SachinSarola, please check that you don't send any output **before** calling `$result = http_response_code(500)`. Also, please check the actual value returned in the `$result` variable to ensure that the operation completed succesfully.